# How to flip the two LinearLayout from right to left and left to right

Tags: android, animation

I have two `LinearLayout` in my `screen`.

The first one should be visible and the second should be invisible at the time of activity launching . By pressing a `button` in first `Linearlayout` the first `LinearLayout` should be `invisible` and the second one should be `visible`.

But **I want some animation at the time of invisible and invisible state.**like by the time when the `1st` is invisible  it should `animate` towards right side of the screen the will invisible and the `2nd` one should come from the `leftside` of the `screen` by giving `animating` effect.

Comment: why negative vote if it is  difficult to understand the question please ping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok this would be the answer for your question 
first hide the second LinearLayout in the xml layout file by using the tag `android:visibility="invisible"`because you dont want it for the first time while activity is launching then create `anim` folder inside the `res` folder there create two animation xml files like `flip_in_left`,`flip_in_right` in
**flip_in_left.xml**

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    />
```

then in **flip_in_right.xml** apply

```
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    />
```

get the Ids of your two `LinearLayout's`

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
LinearLayout layout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
```

By clicking on the `Button`
inside the `onClickListener`

```
layout1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,flip_in_right));
layout.setVisible(View.GONE);
layout2.setVisible(View.VISIBLE)
layout1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,flip_in_left));
```

like this you can do

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, -viewWidth, 0, 0); // To animate to the left. To animate right, remove the "-".
        animation.setDuration(500);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {               
                myView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        myView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: Where you have written to go left to right and right to left and this may not the appropriate answer for my question.

Comment: @kalyanpvs first understand my question what i have said is for linerarlayout or any views what link u have posted is for activity so i cant apply overridePendingTransition here in  views or layout.

Comment: @kalyanpvs lol really you should read the question properly ,did you understood what he was asking .

Comment: this is not the place for these kinds of arguments guys. im sorry i misunderstood your question man.

Answer (score 0):

create anim folder in res and create xml like slie_out_left.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

this is another xml file name is silde_in_right.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

and get the animation in your activity using this

```
Animation anim1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_out_left);
Animation anim2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.slide_in_right);
```

apply this animations to respected layouts. and maintain the respective visibility functionalities.

Comment: This is quite near i can say very close what i was looking

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html  look at this link properly, and then ask what really you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
                holder.layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                        _context, R.animator.left_anim);
                animation.setDuration(500);
                holder.layout.setAnimation(animation);
                holder.layout.animate();
```

**If you are not in activity class**

```
here is the left_anim xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="500"
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:toXDelta="0%" >
</translate>
```